# Generating a word list with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if there is way of creating an array that will create words with length n from a-z like:
n=3

```
    aaa
    aab
    aac
    ...
    xyz
```

and so on. I know that

```
   puts ('aa'..'zz').each { |letter| p letter }
```

will give me what I need but how can I implement it to where I dont have to change

```
   ('aa'..'zz')
```

every time and I can just change n (n being the numbers of a's and z's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there

```
n = 3
(('a'*n)..('z'*n)).each { |letter| puts letter }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'zz'
(26**3).times.map { s=s.next }
  #=> ["aaa", "aab",..., "zzy", "zzz"]
```

Comment: nice one but the length of the words must be configurable. you could do **s = 'z'*(n-1)** but doesn't work when **n** == 1